# How to count number of filtered columns in django with fk?

Tags: django

In the bellow code the user_name is foreign key. I want to get the name and I am getting fk id.

```
test.objects.filter(status='present').order_by('user_name').values('user_name').annotate(dcount=Count('status'))
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you want. Can you specify what you want to retrieve (and the relevant models)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you want a count of all the `test` objects with `status='present'`. Try:

```
test.objects.filter(status='present').count()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. this will get the count of all attendance with status present.   context['attendance_obj']=Attendance.objects.filter(status='present').order_by('user_name').values('user_name').annotate(dcount=Count('status'))